# How to embed an infographic iframe in android's webview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am new to android development and i'm doing a an app where i need to embed an iframe in android's webview..
iframe sample is

```
<iframe src="//e.infogr.am/chart-61108188168" width="550" height="680" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just set up a simple webview pointing to the iFrames url like so?

Create a webview in the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Then in your code set it up as:

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webcontent);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("http://websitesby.projectcaruso.com/");
}

}
```